# Why do these water lines have capped stubs beside them

Tags: plumbing

Lines feeding laundry and kitchen both have these additional capped pipes adjacent to the lines and prior the valves.  Is it just an arrestor or can they be used to tap other things in?

[image: Picture of plumbing in question]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

Comment: See here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/224847/when-you-are-adding-new-pipes-segments-to-existing-lines-and-they-are-capped-at/224849#224849

Comment: That is a [water hammer arrestor](https://www.google.com/search?q=water+hammer+arrestor) (field fabricated).

Comment: Water hammers, done wrong. The flow is to travel through the tee unimpeded. The valve should come out of the tee, and then use two street elbows to get the bottom of the tee back up to vertical.

Answer (score 13):

In all likelihood (and I'm not a plumber), but they are probably to prevent water hammering.  They will hold some air that will compress when the water is suddenly stopped. That way it won't "shake the pipes" and make noise.  There are also commercially available devices to prevent water hammering. Do not consider them for other purposes unless you T-in very low and/or extend the length of them.

Comment: Worth noting that washing machine valves are notorious for using fast-closing solenoid valves which abruptly stop water and cause water hammer.

Comment: YT video on the subject :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoLmVFAFjn4 (Practical Engineering - What is Water Hammer?)

Comment: These vertical pipes can act as water hammer arrestors, but the air in them will slowly dissolve into the water until the entire pipe is filled with water, and it will no longer mitigate water hammer effects.  Commercial water hammer arrestors are available with flexible membranes between the water and gas to prevent this.

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe this isn't allowed in the building code where I live, since no "dead end" pipes are allowed longer than the diameter of the pipe.  The reason is to prevent buildup in pipe sections without a flow, that may promote bacterial growth. If it's vertically mounted like this just above the outlet, then I'm not sure what the actual risks are.

Comment: @KarlP  I DK where they are legal or not, but i agree, I don't like the approach due to what MackM said, the air will eventually get absorbed, leaving it non-functional.  You could drain the entire system occasionally blow it out with compressed air and hopefully get air back into them.   Maybe a valve on top and fittings to connect a compressor and recharge 'em, still that's a maintenance hassle.  I think the commercial ones are better.

Answer (score 2):

Old design water hammer arrestors, but not a type that is generally permitted now.

The concern is that the stagnant water trapped in the dead leg, once the trapped air has diffused through the water, can be a printer breeding ground for legionella bacteria.

I actually just came across a video talking about these a couple days ago:
https://youtu.be/FbkE0HhEHVY